# Using Proc export to a xlsx Google sheet (gsheet) - via SAS/WPS

Tags: sas, xlsx, proc, wps

I'm currently using WPS 3.3 and need to export a table into a Google Sheet (XLSX gsheet) on a weekly basis.  Unfortunately, I haven't so far been able to identify a solution which works for me.  The drive I am trying to access is mapped to my drive and I an owner of the file.

I have tested the following with a simple dummy dataset:

Dummy Data:

```
"data x;
x = 12;
y = 3;
p=4;
run;"
```

1)

```
"Proc export
    data = x
    dbms = xlsx
    outfile = "C:\xx\xx\Google Drive\xxx\TT.xlsx"
    replace;
run;"
```

Which produces a xlsx document in my Google drive but it is still an excel sheet and therefore required converting to a "gsheet"

2)`ODS options`: is not an option available on WPS

3) `ODS EXCELXP` creates a corrupt file on the Google drive.

I wanted to know if anyone knows a solution to creating and updating Google sheets via WPS/SAS that has worked for them?

Edit:

So I couldn't identify a programmatic answer to this {Yet}.

However, I found a tool called "sheetGO" which is a Google add-on. This connects to any excel sheet output from my WPS sessions and updates the google sheet at a  scheduled time.

You can also use it in reverse (google sheet to xls/xlsx).
Link:
https://www.sheetgo.com/

However, if anyone can suggest an answer which does not require a secondary tool please let me know.